# is there any solve for top comma erorr

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have got error because of top comma which contains in name.
Here is product name CP Büyük Boy Yumurta (15'li) .
How can I solve this top comma problem?

```
formula: QUERY(A:D;"Select A,B,C,D" & if(COUNTBLANK(Helper!A1)=1;"";" Where " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ";TRUE;Helper!A1));1)
```

[image]

```
=QUERY(A:D;"Select A,B,C,D" & if(COUNTBLANK(Helper!A1)=1;"";" Where " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ";TRUE;Helper!A1));1)
```

Comment: What does your Helper's A1 look like completely?

Comment: IS this Excel or Google Shet? Please, use the right tag. Also, it's not a comma, it's a single quote like `'` and that char is used in SQL to delimit string values. Anyways, make it double LIKE `''` using [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en). Try something like `QUERY(A:D;"Select A,B,C,D" & if(COUNTBLANK(Helper!A1)=1;"";" Where " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ";TRUE;SUBSTITUTE(Helper!A1;"'";"''")));1)`